# Rails 4 has_one / accepts_nested_attributes works locally, but not on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I've got a simple `post` model in my Rails 4 app that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :slide`. Everything is setup and running fine on my local machine in dev mode, but it throws this error on both heroku and a digital ocean server:

```
 app/web.1: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: post_id):
 app/web.1:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:12:in `new'
```

these are the controller lines in question, line 12 referenced above is the 3rd line below:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.build_slide
end
```

I doubled checked and there are no pending migrations on my server or heroku and both are up-to-date with the git repo. Both the local dev and remote repos are running postgres. Everything checks out in irb as well:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > a = Post.new
=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, en_body: nil, ko_body: nil, short_title: nil, created_at: nil,    updated_at: nil, published: nil, slug: nil, ko_title: nil>
2.0.0-p247 :002 > a.build_slide
=> #<Slide id: nil, en_title: nil, ko_title: nil, en_description: nil, ko_description: nil, active: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, link: nil, anchor: nil, post_id: nil>
```

Why could the servers be complaining about an unknown attribute?

Comment: try restarting your server?
i did happened with me once on heroku, I had to restart the heroku server after executing migration.
Restart heroku server using 'heroku restart' from your rails app directory.

Comment: cheers, that fixed heroku. still waiting for my server to restart...digital ocean seems to be having some issues at the moment.

Comment: I am not aware of issues at digital ocean. But I am sure when it is up, your problem will be resolved by restarting the server.
Can you please mark my answer correct as it solved your problem?

Comment: I would still replace `:slide` with `:slides`. That will throw errors sooner or later.

Comment: why do you think so? it's a ``has_one``` association. Sorry, should've posted the model, that would've been clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your heroku server
it did happened with me once on heroku, 
I had to restart the heroku server after executing migration. 
Restart heroku server using

```
heroku restart
```

from your rails app directory.